# Get max ID for every Type and every Date from a lookup table

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I want to keep the highest report id (Report_ID) for every type (Types) for every single date (Date)

**Note:** The data column has multiple dates, only 01.01.2021 is shown below.

**Question:** t1 is the lookup table that I need to use and my challenge is that it does not contain a date column for reference.

```
select t2.*
from t2
where t1.Report_ID = (select max(t1.Report_ID)
                     from t1
                     where t2.Date = ??? and t2.Types = ???
                    );
```

**t1**

| Report_ID | Name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Name 1 | Value 1 |
| 2 | Name 2 | Value 2 |
| 3 | Name 3 | Value 3 |

**t2**

| Date | Types | Report_ID | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2020 | Type 1 | 1 | Name 1 |
| 01.01.2020 | Type 1 | 2 | Name 2 |
| 01.01.2020 | Type 3 | 3 | Name 3 |

**view**

| Date | Types | Name | Value | Report_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2020 | Type 1 | Name 2 | Value 2 | 2 |
| 01.01.2020 | Type 3 | Name 3 | Value 3 | 3 |

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: It clearly says SQL.

Comment: Please, [**do not post images of data**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). You can check [SQL tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) to check how to create an answerable SQL question.

Comment: @astentx corrected. Thanks.

Comment: @MoeAmine You don't need date column in t1 for reference since you have report_id in both the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this query:

```
SELECT Date, Types, MAX(Report_ID) Report_ID
FROM t2
GROUP BY Date, Types
```

you get the max `Report_ID` for each `Date` and `Types`

Join it to `t1`:

```
SELECT t2.Date, t2.Types, t1.Name, t1.Value, t1.Report_ID
FROM t1 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT Date, Types, MAX(Report_ID) Report_ID
  FROM t2
  GROUP BY Date, Types
) t2 ON t2.Report_ID = t1.Report_ID
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e68a5ed6cebec6a5045a198fe1898de3).
Results:

| Date | Types | Name | Value | Report_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | Type 1 | Name 2 | Value 2 | 2 |
| 2020-01-01 | Type 3 | Name 3 | Value 3 | 3 |

Answer (score 1):

Using [ROW_NUMBER()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql/46753800#46753800):

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT t2.*, t1.Value, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY `Date`, Types ORDER BY Report_ID DESC) AS rn
  FROM t2
  JOIN t1 ON t1.Report_ID = t2.Report_ID
)
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE rn = 1;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5d89fccf40b6db56c50f06ad01d593ee)**

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original version of the question.

> I want to keep the highest report id (Report_ID) for every type (Types) for every single date (Date)

The reference table is not needed for this.  Your logic should do what you want with `t2` in the subquery:

```
select t2.*
from t2
where t2.Report_ID = (select max(tt2.Report_ID)
                      from t2 tt2
                      where tt2.Date = t2.date and tt2.Type = t2.Type
                     );
```

Comment: Sorry, I added by mistake Type in t1. It does not have it in fact.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` as follows:

```
select t2.*
  from t2 
  --join t1 on t1.Report_ID = t2.Report_ID -- use it if you want data from t1 in SELECT 
where not exists 
      (select 1 from t2 t22 
        where t22.date = t2.date and t22.type = t2.type 
          and t22.Report_ID > t2.Report_ID)
```

Comment: Sorry, I added by mistake Type in t1. It does not have it in fact.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve that through row_number() and CTE. First we need to join t1 and t2 to get the **value** column from t1. We used row_number() to put a sequence number in every row starting from highest Report_ID to lowest for a particular type in a given date.
Then we only consider the rows with lowest sequence number which represents highest report_id for any particular type of a given da.

```
With cte as
  (
select t2.date,t2.types,t2.report_id,t2.name ,t1.value ,row_number () over (partition by date,types order by t2.report_id desc) RowNumber 
    from t2 inner join  t1 on t2.report_id=t1.report_id 
  )
  select  date_format(date,"%Y.%m.%d") date,types,name,value,report_id from cte where RowNumber=1
```

**Output:**
[image]